# Firebase query for extracting nested data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want extract data from this datastructure where user_id_2 == 2.
For this, I'm writing this syntax :

```
var myDataRef1 = new Firebase('https://*****.firebaseio.com/mails/1/mail');
myDataRef1.orderByChild("user_id_2").equalTo(2).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        var mails = snapshot.val();
        alert(mails.body.subject);
        displayChatMessage(mails.body.subject, mails.body.message);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no path `/mails/1/mail`, because in the real JSON there is a push id in between `1` and `mail`.

Instead try

```
var myDataRef1 = new Firebase('https://bbz-workstation.firebaseio.com/mails/1');
var query = myDataRef1.orderByChild('mail/user_id_2').equalTo(2)...
```

You'll need an index like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "mails: {
      "1": {
        "$pushid": {
          ".indexOn": ["mail/user_id_2"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```